# "After all 7 8 9" joke?

Tags: meaning, humor, puns

I know that it is very important to be aware of "hidden meanings" of words and phrases. (Especially if the meaning is sexual.) That is why I love Stephen Colbert's "The Word" segments and usually spend some time to "decipher" all the puns

But I am really stuck with [the recent one](http://www.colbertnation.com/the-colbert-report-videos/413407/april-30-2012/the-word---don-t-ask--don-t-show---tell). Particularly I cannot understand the `"After all 7 8 9"` line here. From the reaction of the audience I can tell that it is something pretty funny.  And from the context I feel that it is something pretty dirty...

I really don't want to be misunderstood by saying bunch of numbers. So can someone explain what is going on here, so I can avoid that?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just listened, and found it hilarious.  In fact, I ate it up.  By the way, are you living in Missouri?  Because, if you are, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to explain homophones...

Comment: Absolutely. As our schools have proven increasingly unable to teach students math, science, and history, they have to find a new role to justify their continued existence. And now they have: tellling young people the correct opinion to have on controversial social and political subjects.

Comment: @J.R - why, are they homophonobic ?

Comment: To illustrate this joke, [here's a link](http://reboot.wikia.com/wiki/Seven) to ReBoot CG animated series wiki with said joke played by digits (characters) in one of the episodes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

read it as

> Seven **ate** Nine

:)

Comment: This is the reason why 6 is afraid of 7.